# CSS cascading rules for html controls

Tags: html, css

why CSS rules do not cascade down automatically to HTML controls like input or select and style the display of text in them?

For Ex: I have a css class applied on the body tag that renders text in red.
Due to cascading rules, all the text in that html document is rendered in red (unless overridden). But if i have a textbox control in that document, the style does not cascade into the textbox to render the text in it in red.

Could someone point me to a reference document that talks about that??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is the default CSS styles as determined by your browser.

- `input` and `select` have default colors/sizes/padding etc.
- Most other elements use `inherit` for color and size.
- Another example is the font-size of `table` which is fixed and not inherited by default, and must be overridden by the developer.

Try this example HTML:

```
<html>

<style type="text/css">
body { color:red; font-size:36px; }
</style>

<body>
Hello
<input type="text" value="test value"/>
<table><tr><td>cell value</td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

You will see that the `font-size` and `color` were not inherited by the `input`.  Also, the cell value stayed at the default font size.  Now add the following CSS to the `style` block:

```
input { color:inherit; font-size:inherit; }
table { font-size:inherit; }
```

You'll see that they inherit as you expected now.

**What you really want to do is use a reset stylesheet**. Tables are just one element that has a default style attached that isn't desirable for many developers, and every browser might be slightly different. This is why many make use of **reset css** stylesheets.  These stylesheets reset most elements to uniform sizes and zero margins, padding, etc. Some are more extreme than others. See http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ or [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=reset+css) for an example.

Since most reset stylesheets don't make colors of `input` and `select` inherit (most developers don't want them to inherit and instead want to explicitly set size/color), you should set them in your stylesheet:

```
input, select { ... }
```

**Be careful** with `* { ... }` for *any* purpose (as suggested by the other answer).  This **breaks** the "cascading" part of CSS and will cause rules not to cascade as you would expect in nested elements.  If you use `* { color:red; }` and then have the following HTML:

```
<h1 style="color:green;">Hello <i>world</i></h1>
```

You will end up with a green **Hello** and a *red* **world**. (Because the `<i>` matches `*`. Any new element will reset the style back to red, and color no longer cascades at all!)

Comment: +1 for "be careful with * {...}".  You are absolutely right about that. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Some html elements have default styles set based on the doctype and browser (and even version of the browser).  These styles might be margins, width, padding, or even text color.

That said, if you want a particular thing like "color: red;" to apply to everything then you should use:

```
* { color: red;}
```

The * (asterisk) matches everything and would cause ALL elements to display their font color in red. Unless a more specific css rule applied.

You might look at [this page](http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/css-inheritance-cascade/) for more information.

I believe (someone correct me if this isn't right) the fall through rule list is:

1. Browser default
2. general css rules (`input { blah }`)
3. id rules (`#topdiv { blah }`)
4. specific css rules ( `class="xx"`)
5. style settings (`style='color:blue;`)

I'm not sure where implicit and explicit inherited styles fall, but you should get the idea.